\href inside bib xref causes "TeX capacity exceeded, sorry"
I am using amsrefs with hyperref to create a bibliography.  I want to typeset a link using \href.  This works fine in most situations, but it causes an error if \href is used in a \bib* entry that is referenced by an "xref" item in another \bib entry.
Following is a small example that shows the problem.  It contains a couple of notes on minor changes that cause the error to vanish.  In particular, \href used in an ordinary \bib entry seems to work fine.
% Fails with message
%    TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].

\pdfoutput=1

\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[lite]{amsrefs}

% Cribbed from the definition of \MR in amsart.cls.
\newcommand\Zbl[1]{\relax\ifhmode\unskip\spacefactor3000 \space\fi
% If the following line is replaced by the one after that, the error vanishes.
  \href{https://zbmath.org/#1}{Zbl~#1}}
%  Zbl~#1}

\begin{document}

\section{Annotated bibliography}

\begin{biblist}

\bib*{xref-BogFreesKung1990}{book}{
    title = {The Dilworth theorems:  selected papers of Robert P.\ Dilworth},
    editor = {Bogard, Kenneth P.},
% If the following line is commented out, the error vanishes.
    review = {\Zbl{0907.06001}},
}

\bib{BogFreesKung1990}{book}{
    label = {BogFreesKung1990},
    xref = {xref-BogFreesKung1990},
}

\bib{DayFrees1990}{article}{
    label = {DayFrees1990},
    author = {Day, Alan},
    title = {The Role of Gluing Constructions in Modular Lattice Theory},
    book = {
        xref = {xref-BogFreesKung1990},
    },
    review = {\Zbl{0907.06001}},
}

\end{biblist}

\end{document}


try with \NewDocumentCommand\Zbl{m}{...}
